# I'm new to QBasic and coding in general and I'm making a guessing game that just wont work

Tags: qbasic

I'm new to QBasic and coding in general and I'm making a guessing game that just won't work.
I have to make a guessing game that does not use `GOTO` or `Do` statements, and gives the user 5 chances. Here's the code:

```
chances%=1
dim guess as integer
dim answer as string
randomize timer
rndnum=INT(RND*100+1)

'makinng a title
color 5
locate 12,32
print "welcome to My guessing game."
Print "think of a number between 1 and 100."

color 12
Input "enter you guess:  ",guess
while chances%<4
if guess >rndnum then 
  print "wrong, too high"
elseif guess <rndnum then 
   print "wrong, too low"
elseif guess=rndnum then
 print "your guessed the number!"
end if 
wend
chances%=chances%+1

color 14
Print "you took "; chances%;"to guess the number"

color 3
Input would you like to play again (yes/no)?", answer
wend 

if answer = "yes" then
?

else 
  print "have a good day"
end if 
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You are asking for input one time, then you have a closed loop that checks the answer until attempts are greater than four, but attempts does not ever increment because the Wend command tells it to start the loop again without asking the question again or incrementing the counter at all.  This is what is called an "endless loop" because the conditions inside the loop will not change.  I'll leave it at that and see if you can figure out how to correct both of these issues - note that fixing only one of them will not stop it from being an "endless loop" you must solve both.

Answer (score 1):

Your guess must be inside the while wend loop and when the correct answer is given chances% must be set equal to 4 otherwise you end up with an eternal loop.
It is also necessary to increment chances% directly after the first guess.   See the slightly changed code. Please also see guesses and change your line saying you took x guess from chances% to guesses

```
chances%=0
while chances% < 4
    Input "enter your guess:  ",guess
    chances% = chances% + 1
    if guess > rndnum then 
        print "wrong, too high"
    elseif guess < rndnum then 
        print "wrong, too low"
    elseif guess = rndnum then
        print "your guessed the number!"
        guesses = Chances%
        chances% = 4
    end if 
wend
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `WHILE...WEND` to run a loop until chances becomes 0.Here is what I mean:

```
....(rest of code)
chances = 5
WHILE chances > 0 
    ....
    if guess > rndnum then 
       print "wrong, too high"
       chances = chances - 1
    elseif guess < rndnum then 
       print "wrong, too low"
       chances = chances -1
     ....
WEND
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're still having problems I found that here:

```
Input would you like to play again (yes/no)?", answer
```

...

```
if answer = "yes"
```

...

you would have to change answer to answer$ because you cannot save a string inside a number value.

Answer (score 0):

This snip demonstrates a number guessing game in QB64:

```
REM guessing game.
Tries = 5
DO
    PRINT "Guess a number between 1 and 100 in"; Tries; "guesses."
    Number = INT(RND * 100 + 1)
    Count = 1
    DO
        PRINT "Enter guess number"; Count; " ";
        INPUT Guess
        IF Guess = Number THEN
            PRINT "Correct! You guessed it in"; Count; "tries."
            EXIT DO
        END IF
        IF Guess > Number THEN
            PRINT "Wrong. Too high."
        ELSE
            PRINT "Wrong. Too low."
        END IF
        Count = Count + 1
        IF Count > Tries THEN
            PRINT "The number was"; Number
            PRINT "You didn't guess it in"; Tries; "tries."
            EXIT DO
        END IF
    LOOP
    DO
        PRINT "Play again(yes/no)";
        INPUT Answer$
        IF LCASE$(Answer$) = "no" THEN
            END
        END IF
        IF LCASE$(Answer$) = "yes" THEN
            EXIT DO
        END IF
    LOOP
LOOP
END
```

Comment: Of you are still using QB then you should look at the QB64 IDE at www.qb64.net